# declare list of fixed size arrays in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list

I've got a function which operates on pixels. I want to create one list with RGB values, but when I declare it this way:

```
List<int[]> maskPixels = new List<int[3]>();
```

It gives me error:

> Array size cannot be specified in a variable declaration (try initializing with a 'new' expression)

Adding pixels is done like this: `maskPixels.Add(new int[] { Red, Green, Blue });`

Is there a way to do this, or I have to use `new List<int[]>();` instead?

Comment: why don't you use List<Color> instead?

Comment: I'd recommend a `List<Color>` as well. But just to throw out an alternative: have you considered an `int[,]` or `int[,,]` (i.e. multi-dimensional array; the latter could be useful to store x,y,color)? Those, unlike jagged arrays (`int[][]`) or lists of arrays (`List<int[]>`) are always rectangular/cuboid, i.e. you can't have varying numbers of elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible. Think about it for just a second. When you have a generic type, say `List<T>`, `T` is a type parameter and for specific instances of the generic type, you fill in a type `T`.

But `int[3]` is *not* a type! Precisely, it's an *`array-creation-expression`* in the C# grammar.

If you want to limit to a type that can only hold three values, may I suggest as a first cut `Tuple<int, int, int>`? But even better, [I recommend a type dedicated to representing](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/25/DesignSmellPrimitiveObsession/) RGB like [`System.Drawing.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) (use [`Color.FromArgb(int, int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx)) or your own custom type if necessary. The reason I would lean towards the latter is because not all `Tuple<int, int, int>` are valid representations of RGB!

Comment: I completely forgot about Color class. That's the thing I'll use.
And great explanation about `array-creation-expression`; exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

There is no way to do something similar, but since you are using this for RGB values, why don't you use `Color` class instead?

```
List<Color> maskPixels = new List<Color>();
```

And initialize each Color like this:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(R,G,B); //assuming R,G,B are int values
```

If your values are in the range of 0-255 this is the most natural way of storing them. You have predefined getters and setters in order to obtain each color component.

Comment: I would hope that they are in that range. There's not many (or indeed, none AFAIAA) Windows API calls that have RGB values greater than 255...

Comment: @MatthewWatson Offcourse, I was more thinking on some other proprietary color coding used for hardware or I don't know what other purpose. In case OP is storing them before converting to the 0-255 range.

Comment: It would require some more input from the OP, but I wonder if he's going to be doing some maths on these values, and perhaps `Color` is not amenable to do that - but then, who knows at this point, this could be the perfect solution.

Comment: @Moo-Juice Totally agree, that is why I added the disclaimer :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can't do array initialization like this, and further each `int[]` could technically be a different size. How about a different data structure, `List<Tuple<int, int, int>>`?

This would allow you to strictly have three integer values in the list, and it's searchable via LINQ faster than an array because it's a well defined structure with properties.

Comment: +1 `Tuple<T1,T2,T3>` is a far better alternative for small arrays of fixed size.

Comment: The only issue I have with `Tuple` is that you're then referencing the members with `Item1`, `Item2`, and `Item3` which isn't very readable.

Comment: Mind you, I'd argue that using the `Color` struct would be even better if you are, you know, representing colours! :)

Comment: @MatthewWatson, the argument is understandable. That's why I +1'd Nikola's answer.

Comment: @Moo-Juice, I can understand that, and that's why I +1'd your answer as well. It would work just fine and *technically* be more readable. There is always more than one way to skin the cat.

Comment: And when adding, take advantage of the static `Create` method on the non-generic `Tuple` type, that is use: `maskPixels.Add(Tuple.Create(Red, Green, Blue));`. Because it will drive you crazy to have to type `<int, int, int>` all the time.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, that's a great addition.

Comment: @Thomas, fair enough. Consider it if you move to a newer version of the framework.

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest having your own value-type for this:

```
public struct Rgb
{
    int R,
    int G,
    int B
}

List<Rgb> list = new List<Rgb>;
```

Comment: Don't you mean `List<Tuple<Rgb, Rgb, Rgb>>` ?

Comment: @Arion, nope :)  I (believe) the OP wants to store a list of RGB values, not a List of 3 RGB values.

Comment: Since I can't use `Tuple` (.NET 2.0), besides `Color` class, I think this is the best way to go. And I guess this is the only way (struct) for non-color values.

Answer (score -1):

```
 [Flags]
    public enum RGB
    {
        R,
        G,
        B
    }
```

...

```
public List<RGB> l = new List<RGB>();
l.Add(RGB.r | RGB.G)
```

Comment: This would make working with the individual int elements a nightmare.

Comment: Using `struct` is more friendly in my opinion.